# INSERT data into tables in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

There are two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
softwareId VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
version VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
releaseDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE UPDATE_FILE(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
updateId INT,
FOREIGN KEY (updateId) REFERENCES SOFTWARE_UPDATE(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
osName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
osArch VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
filePath VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
fileName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

they have relationship on updateId.
I know how to add data into a table with no relationships.

```
getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,c3) VALUES(?,?,?)");
pStatement.setString(1, version);
pStatement.setString(2, path);
pStatement.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
pStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I'm not sure if adding new data into tables with relationship is the same?

Comment: When you insert into a table you need to be sure that you satisfy all constraints (including foreign key). Please clarify your problem, as it stands it is hard to tell exactly what you are having problems with, and therefor it is not really answerable.

Comment: _adding new data into tables with relationship is the same_ Have you tried? Did you encountered some problems?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My problem is: Do I have to insert new data into two tables with relationship by two `insert command`?

Comment: @SuperHornet That depends, if the foreign key target already exists then no, otherwise yes

Answer (score 0):

It is the same. But may I suggest you use JPA instead of JDBC for this? I think that will be really easy when it comes to complex foreign key mappings. Make sure the database you are using is JPA compatible though.